# Cannot hide back button on action bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar

My application have two top level fragment A and B controlled by a bottom navigation bar and fragment C can be navigated only from fragment B. I don't want the action bar on fragment C shows back button while it cannot be hidden by `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()` or `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`

How can I hide the back button?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.aFragment, R.id.bFragment)
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set home fragment destination

```
var navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
                      .findFragmentById(R.id.container) as NavHostFragment
var mNavController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
    
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return when (mNavController.currentDestination?.id) {
            R.id.homeFrg -> {
                true
            }

            else -> mNavController.navigateUp()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).